# Maintain Focus after onfocus__doPostBack in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have to perform server side event when user clicks in textbox's. So far i can manage that calling a javascript function using onfocus event, but if I try to remove onfocus, do some code, put focus back on the control then it re-fires the onfocus event again in an infinite loop. Sample below...

Html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onfocus="CallServer(this);"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" onfocus="CallServer(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

Javascript

```
function CallServer(obj) {
  if (obj != "") {
    var control = document.getElementById(obj.id)
    __doPostBack(obj.id, "onfocus");
  }
}
```

CodeBehind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   If IsPostBack Then
      Dim target As String = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
      Dim eventarg As String = Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT")
      Dim PostControl As Control = Nothing

      If target <> "" Then
         PostControl = Page.FindControl(target)
      End If

      If eventarg = "onfocus" Then
         CType(PostControl, TextBox).Attributes("onfocus") = "null"

         ...do some code

         Page.SetFocus(PostControl)

         CType(ctrl, TextBox).Attributes.Add("onfocus", "CallServer(this)")
      End If
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the ScriptManager.SetFocus in the Page_PreRender. The ScriptManager in this case is located in MasterPage.

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender

    If HiddenFieldPostBackControl.Value <> "" Then
        Dim PostBackControl As Control = FindControlById(HiddenFieldPostBackControl.Value)
        If PostBackControl IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim sm As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Master.Page)
            sm.SetFocus(PostBackControl )
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Note: If you are working with dynamic controls (which have to be recreated on every postback), you will have to remove the (OnFocus of OnFocusIn) event for the target control while adding the event to the other controls. This has to be done before the Page_PreRender.

```
function ControlOnFocus(ctrl, request, doc, min, max, docSec) {
        if (ctrl != "") {
            var hf = document.getElementById("MainContent_HiddenFieldPostControl").value = ctrl.id;
            var c = document.getElementById(ctrl.id);
            PostControl = ctrl;

            //ONFOCUS
            if (request.toLowerCase() == 'server') {
                //SERVER Handler
                __doPostBack(ctrl.id, "onfocus");
            } else {
                //CLIENT Handler
                //Your code here...
            }

            ReAssignEvent(ctrl.id);

            var hf = document.getElementById("MainContent_hfValidated");
            hf.innerText = "";
        };
    };
 function ReAssignEvent(ControlID) {
        //loop through an array with (id,onfocus event) for each control
        //this array is only required for the focus event

        for (var i = 0; i < FocusArray.length; i++) {

            var carr = FocusArray[i].split("[1]"); //split the element to get id and event
            var carrId = carr[0]; //get the id
            var c = document.getElementById(carrId); //find control and assign control to var
            var e = carr[1]; //assing event as string to var

            if (c != null) {
                if (ControlID!= carrId) {
                    if (c.type == "text" || c.type == "select-one") {
                        c.setAttribute("onfocus", e);
                    } else {
                        c.setAttribute("onfocusin", e);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (c.type == "text" || c.type == "select-one") {
                        c.removeAttribute("onfocus");
                    } else {
                        c.removeAttribute("onfocusin");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
 }
```